# HTML/JavaScript: How to close iframe from parent page by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with a button which creates iframes and appends them to a div:

```
function createIFRAME() {
    $.get("../../../GetIframeID", function(data){
        alert(data);

        ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        ifrm.setAttribute("id", data);
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "chat.html");
        //ifrm.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
        ifrm.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        ifrm.style.width = 304+"px";
        ifrm.style.height = 284+"px";

        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(ifrm);
    });
}
```

Using a servlet with a static attribute I assure the uniqueness of iframe's id.

**Problem:** Each created page (chat.html) contains a button for closing the page. I found the script for closing an iframe from its parent's page, but I couldn't figure out how to get the id of a specific iframe.

```
function closeIframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

When closing the iframe, from page "chat.html" I use:

```
<input id="closeButton" type="image" src="../../../images/closeButton.png" onclick="javascript: window.parent.closeIframe()"" />
```

How can I get the ID of a specific iframe so I can close it with the above function?

Comment: If the problem is solved, please post the solution so that other people can benefit from it.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, not an edit : http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I've changed the function which create iframes and make it like this (I've send the id like parameter to "chat.html"):

```
function createIFRAME() {
            $.get("../../../GetIframeID", function(data){
                alert(data);

                ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
                ifrm.setAttribute("id", data);
                ifrm.setAttribute("src", "chat.html?id="+data);
                //ifrm.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
                ifrm.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
                ifrm.style.width = 304+"px";
                ifrm.style.height = 284+"px";

                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(ifrm);
            });
        }
```

I modified the button for closing frame like this:

```
<input id="closeButton" type="image" src="../../../images/closeButton.png" onclick="closeIFRAME()" />
```

Now I've got 2 functions: one is find in "chat.html" which has role to get the id of page from URL and send it as parameter to second function which is located in iframe's parent.

**function closeIFRAME()** (from "chat.html"):

```
function closeIFRAME() {
            alert("1");
            var param1var = getQueryVariable("id");

            function getQueryVariable(variable) {
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var vars = query.split("&");
                for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    if (pair[0] == variable) {
                        return pair[1]; 
                    }
                }
            }

            parent.closeIframe(param1var);
        }
```

**function closeIframe(id)** (from iframe's parent):

```
function closeIframe(id) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
            iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        }
```

**Thank you all for support!**

Answer (score 0):

You can try transmitting the iFrame's ID in the button's onclick.

```
<input id="closeButton" type="image" src="../../../images/closeButton.png" onclick="javascript: window.parent.closeIframe([insert iframes ID here])"" />
```

Hope it'll help.

Anyway, the technologies you are using are from another age. Iframes ?
Go for ajax, much easier to use now.
I would even say websockets are easier to use with nodejs for a chat (but everything depends on the rest of your website).

You maybe also can try onclick="window.parent.removeChild(window)" (totally unsure if this works)